# How to call a function from another class in python->sikuli?

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

How can i access methods of channel1 in channel2 so that test_script1,test_script2 is execute first and then test_script3,test_script4.

**Note**:- The main issue is when i am executing 
suite1= unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(channel1) and
suite2= unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(channel2), i am getting two reprort tables.

But instead i want them to merge in one table consisting data of channel1 and channel2 classes both.

```
from sikuli import *
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner

class channel1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_script1(self):
        assert exists("1453186120180.png")
    def test_script2(self):
         assert exists("1453186901719.png")

class channel2(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_script3(self):
        assert exists("1453186120180.png")
    def test_script4(self):
         assert exists("1453186901719.png")
    #channel2().test_script1()
#suite1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(_main_channel.channel1)
#ch1=channel1.test_script1()
#ch2=channel1.test_script2()
suite2= unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(channel2)
#suite2 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(obj2)
outfile = open("D:\\report.html", "wb") # path to report folder

#runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile, title=' Report Title', description='desc..' ).run(suite1)
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile, title=' Report Title', description='desc..' ).run(suite1)
#runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile, title=' Report Title', description='desc..' ).run(suite2)
#runner.run(suite2)
```

Please help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function from another class in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432564/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-class-in-python)

Comment: In the above scenario i want to use methods of channel1 in channel2 so that i can get consolidated report while executing  suite2= unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(channel2)

Comment: my query is different @wogsland

Comment: i want one consolidated report consisting datas of channel 1 and channel 2